# What happens after my trial time expires?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've obtained a code from Blizzard for 30 day of WoW + TBC + WotLK. I clicked upgrade on my account and it somehow upgraded with the 10 day time restriction to Cataclysm. However, the installer downloaded all expansions, including Mists of Pandaria.

I started the game with a Goblin Hunter (this race is part of the Cataclysm expansion, I believe).

On the map I see Pandaria too, and I can choose Pandaren as a playable race, but I can't choose the Monk class.

What will happen when the 10 day Cataclysm upgrade expires?

What will happen if the 30 day trial of Lich King will expire, and I'll renew for another 30 days?

Will my goblin become unplayable?

What's more - what will happen if now (in Cataclysm), I try to get to Pandaria? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Cataclysm (I think? Maybe only Pandaria), races are no longer locked to a particular expansion. This means that if you only have the base game, you can't play death knights or monks, but you can play a worgen/draenei/blood elf / goblin / pandaren starting from level 1.

The various expansion packs only limit access to higher levels, higher level zones, and certain tradeskills (Archaeology comes to mind). And, of course, anything that requires a minimum level higher than what you're able to achieve.

Comment: WotLK now comes standard with all accounts (Battle Chest), so Death Knight (Class) and Inscription (Profession) are now standard with the game and no longer restricted to buying the expansion, as well as the level 80 cap and access to Outlands and Northrend. You still need Cataclysm for flying in Kalimdor and Eastern Kingdoms, as well as Archeology and level cap raised from 80 to 85. And you will need Mists of Pandaria expansion to play Monk (Class) and gain access to Pandaria and level cap of 90 (from 85).